# Pandas - Return last/first day of the month in a custom Datetime Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using a multi index columns dataframe with custom dates (specific holidays,weekdays..).

```
DatetimeIndex(['1989-01-31', '1989-02-01', '1989-02-02', '1989-02-03',
           '1989-02-06', '1989-02-07', '1989-02-08', '1989-02-09',
           '1989-02-10', '1989-02-13',
           ...
           '2019-02-25', '2019-02-26', '2019-02-27', '2019-02-28',
           '2019-03-01', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-05', '2019-03-06',
           '2019-03-07', '2019-03-08'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=7585, freq=None)
```

I need to slice it for first or last day of the month from the index.
Due to holidays,... some first/last day of the month of the index would not match with freq = 'BM'. No need to mention i cannot use resample(),...

Here an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['1989-01-31', '1989-02-01', '1989-02-02', '1989-02-03','1989-02-06', '1989-02-07', '1989-02-08', '1989-02-09','1989-02-10', '1989-02-13', '2019-02-25', '2019-02-26', '2019-02-27', '2019-02-28','2019-03-01', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-05', '2019-03-06','2019-03-07', '2019-03-08'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

numbers = [0, 1, 2]
colors = [u'green', u'purple']
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([numbers, colors],names=['number', 'color'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(idx),len(col)),index =idx,columns=col)
```

```
number            0                 1                 2         
color         green   purple    green   purple    green   purple
2018-06-05  0.64943  0.64943  0.64943  0.64943  0.64943  0.64943
etc...
```

Expected Output:

```
2018-06-29  0.64943  0.64943  0.64943  0.64943  0.64943  0.64943
```

How could i do this please ?

thanks

Comment: Close enough to make a working example of it for you.  Also added random number matrix for data so that you can see the result of operations you apply to the groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `Grouper` on your DataFrame.  Using the mcve in the above question:

```
# Month End
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).last()

# Month Start
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS')).first()
```

Note: Grouping in this manner groups by the DateTimeIndex month, whose group min and max months are calendrical and not necessarily in the index.

So we can go after a grouping of our own, requiring attention to months repeating over the years.

```
grpr = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month])
data = []
for g, gdf in grpr:
    data.append(gdf.loc[gdf.index.min()])
    data.append(gdf.loc[gdf.index.max()])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
new_df
number             0                   1                   2          
color          green    purple     green    purple     green    purple
1989-01-31  0.246601  0.915123  0.105688  0.645864  0.845655  0.339800
1989-01-31  0.246601  0.915123  0.105688  0.645864  0.845655  0.339800
1989-02-01  0.694509  0.665852  0.593890  0.715831  0.474022  0.011742
1989-02-13  0.770202  0.452575  0.935573  0.554261  0.235477  0.475279
2019-02-25  0.626251  0.826958  0.617132  0.118507  0.079782  0.183616
2019-02-28  0.740565  0.131821  0.968403  0.981093  0.211755  0.806868
2019-03-01  0.812805  0.379727  0.758403  0.345361  0.908825  0.166638
2019-03-08  0.238481  0.045592  0.740523  0.201989  0.432714  0.672510
```

It is correct to see duplication because `gdf.index.min()` may equal `gdf.index.max()`.  A check would eliminate duplication when iterating over the groups.